# granting minimal permissions during facebook "Login Flow for Web"

Tags: facebook, server-side

I have implemented a server-side login flow for a facebook page management application to allow my users to grant the necessary permissions to this application. So far, this works nicely and allows my application to obtain a "page access token" after being granted the manage_pages permission.

However, during the login flow, the facebook UI on facebook.com requests both the manage_pages permission (which is what I asked for) and the permission to see the list of friends of the user (which I did not ask for).

To be specific, I redirect the user to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=...&redirect_uri=...&state=...&response_type=code&scope=manage_pages.

Is there a way to convince the facebook UI to *not* request permission from the user to see his list of friends ?

Answer (score 0):

For reference, since I spent a good amount of time researching an answer to that question, I believe that it is impossible to explicitely *not* request permission from the user to see his list of friends. The Facebook documentation hints at this by stating that these are the "default" permissions that every application gets.